# how to convert text file to mp3 using audiosegment in python

Tags: python, binary, text-files, mp3, pydub

so i have file text contains with binary number 1 and 0. i want to make the text file to mp3 file and i found [pydub](https://pydub.com/). but i got error:

> [Errno 22] Invalid argument:
> 'F:\KULIAH\SEMESTER8\SKRIPSI\MusicLockApp\txt\done.txt'

i just trying to open my file and try the pydub.
can someone fix my code?

```
def readbinaryfinal():
    audio = "F:\KULIAH\SEMESTER8\SKRIPSI\MusicLockApp\txt\done.txt"

    sound = AudioSegment.from_file(audio, "txt")
    sound.export("media/em/", format="mp3", bitrate="128l")
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like those slashes need escaping...
`'F:\\KULIAH\\SEMESTER8\\SKRIPSI\\MusicLockApp\\txt\\done.txt'`

(Or change them to forward slashes, / if python in windows copes with that?)

Comment: i tried this and i got new error :  
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified